# View Scheduled Tasks (local and remote) on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server

In one of our production nodes which runs on Windows Server 2008 R2, we have noticed that there is a significant delay (5 times normal) in processing requests (by our application running on tomcat) during Saturday mornings (00:00AM till about 07:30AM). The application provider has asked us to provide the tasks which are scheduled to run during that time period for trouble shooting.

Is there any way I can view all the scheduled tasks (local and remotely triggered) which runs during that period? It would be great if I can see some sort of history of all the scheduled tasks which ran for the past, say five Saturday mornings.

I tried Task Scheduler. However it displays only the local schedules and there is no apparent way to filter the view to show only those which are relevant to the case (Saturday morning in this case).

Comment: Isn't scheduled tasks an OS thing?

Comment: Yes. But the application vendor wants the data to analyse the issue (may be simulate the conditions in their machine).